# IPhone : What is the best practice to create application which shows 50 objective questions one by one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile

IPhone : What is the best practice to create application which shows 50 objective questions one by one. End of the test user should be able to see the score on the UI.
For storing the questions am using SQLLite DB, stored all my questions in a table and retrieved/stored locally in to NSMutable Array. 
Now I have no idea how to navigate between questions "One By One" I guess UI navigation  is one I want but Am puzzled how to use UI Navigation view to show question one by one , please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for each question. The problem is that you have 50 elements to be shown and probably that is too much (Because you surely get at least memory warnings)

In order to avoid memory warnings and to do this efficiently you want to implement a 3-views stack-like structure. For instance, views will be A,B and C.

```
...C←→A←→B←→C←→A...
```

For example you an in B, then you want to navigate to the previous(left) question you will save current question state, load in A and its state the previous view and show it. Now next and previous questions will be loaded in B and C views respectively. Not complicated, right?

You can simulate this structure with a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and 3 UIViewControllers,
each UIViewController should be able to load and save a question with its state just before appearing and disappearing.

You can navigate programmatically using the following methods from UINavigationController and get animated transitions for free ;)

```
– pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The only problem with the push/pop method is that the transitions move in different directions. One potential "fix" is to push a view controller, then remove lower view controllers from the navigation stack manually.

Comment: If I understand correct , at any given point of time 3 questions will be loaded -1 (1) +1. Am little confused now after reading few blogs , could you please clear me one basic question ,I have good experience in switching between "two" views. "First view" with button label "Load Next View" and on click of the button  push them     [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];For this scenarior only my data is going to change according to what the user clicks next/previous , how can I load the same Question view with transition/updating question?

Comment: Create a method - (void) loadQuestion:(MyQuestion *)question{ ... } and call that method before pushViewController:animated: method or any time you want to updated the view controller. Regarding animation, simply load the same question in a different view controller and push it and remove the previous one. Actually, it does not matter what controller you use as long you have the previous question behind the current one ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recently created an App like this for a client. My strategy was to have an IntroViewController, QuestionViewController, and ScoreViewController.

The QuestionViewController housed a UIControl subclass I created to visualize a Question object. The QuestionViewController interacts with a TestManager object to pull the list of questions, it responds to the input from the UIControl subclass, then assign a new question to the UIControl.

My strategy keeps memory low by avoiding creating a huge stack of view controllers. I utilized CATransitions to give the user a sense of new screens for each question.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for sharing your experience , I never tried CATransitions Am going to give a try now. Also let me know what is your thoughts on this approach http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: You can use that method; I don't particularly like it as you'll have 3 view controller in memory at any one time. The transitions will give you the same user experience, but limit your view controllers to 1.

Comment: One more basic question how to apply transition for the QuestionViewController for different questions? Logically there is will be only one view for displaying the question assuming there will be 10 question. Now if the user answered first question there is going to be two action change the question and apply transition. Is the transition is inbuilt one - If you have any example URL plz share.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess I got the answer , please ignore my previous question.thanks for your time.